# Unicode characters replaced with question marks when scraping web page in Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, web-scraping, urllib2

I have some simple python code that scrapes a webpage with urllib2:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
charset = response.headers.getheader("Content-Type")
charset = charset[charset.index("charset=") + 8:]
html = response.read()
html = " ".join(html.split())
html = html.decode(charset)
html = html.replace("amp;", "").replace("&#039;", "'")
```

My problem is that the page I am scraping has Te Reo Māori words in it and therefore it has many words containing macrons, eg. "Pūtaiao." When I print the HTML, all of the macron letters are replaced with question marks, and I haven't used any replace decoding method. It even happens without any decoding, splitting or joining.

There is also another page on the same site that contains some of the same words and the macrons display completely fine in python. I have also noticed that that page's charset in its response headers is utf-8, while the page with the question marks is in ISO-8859-1, so that could have something to do with it.

The link to the site with the question marks is http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/ncea/assessment/search.do?query=reo+maori&view=all&level=01.

The other page is http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/qualifications-standards/qualifications/ncea/subjects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the server responds with wrong content-type when it does not recognize the user agent that the request came from. I got similar result when I tried it on my machine.

After adding a valid `User-Agent` to the request header, I was able to correctly get the `utf-8` encoding for the response. I am not sure if this would be the best fix for this case, but it should get your code working. Example -

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers = {"Connection":"keep-alive", "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
#After this rest of your original code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using requests and beautiful soup on your first link.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/ncea/assessment/search.do?     query=reo+maori&view=all&level=01"
headers= {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
# print(r.content)
print(r.encoding)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
data = r.text
data1 = data.encode('UTF-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data1)
text = soup.get_text()
text2 = text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
# text2 = text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
print(text2)
```

Which text2 line depends on what you are trying to do next.

Note using headers as suggested by Anand